# Bootstrap snippet pack and web essentials is not installing on VS 2015 for web

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio, web-essentials

I've downloaded VS 2015 for web and i want to use bootstrap snippet and web essentials 2015 on it but whenever i try to install any of these things it shows an error message stating that "This extension is not installable on currently installed products"

Prior to VS 2015 i was using VS 2012 and i've uninstalled it already.
What should i do.

Please Help!

The installation log file for bootstrap snippet is as follows:

```
2/16/2016 9:02:47 AM -  Locale             : en-US
2/16/2016 9:02:47 AM -  MoreInfoURL        :                     https://github.com/elebetsamer/bootstrap-snippets-visual-studio
2/16/2016 9:02:47 AM -  InstalledByMSI     : False
2/16/2016 9:02:47 AM -  SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.5,)
2/16/2016 9:02:47 AM - 
2/16/2016 9:02:47 AM -  SignatureState     : Unsigned
2/16/2016 9:02:47 AM -  Supported Products : 
2/16/2016 9:02:47 AM -      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
2/16/2016 9:02:47 AM -          Version : [11.0]
2/16/2016 9:02:47 AM -      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
2/16/2016 9:02:47 AM -          Version : [12.0]
2/16/2016 9:02:47 AM -      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
2/16/2016 9:02:47 AM -          Version : [14.0]
2/16/2016 9:02:47 AM - 
2/16/2016 9:02:47 AM -  References         : 
2/16/2016 9:02:47 AM - Signature Details...
2/16/2016 9:02:47 AM -  Extension is not signed.
2/16/2016 9:02:47 AM - 
2/16/2016 9:02:47 AM - Searching for applicable products...
2/16/2016 9:02:47 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio  Express 2015 for Web
2/16/2016 9:02:47 AM - Found installed product - Global Location
2/16/2016 9:02:47 AM - Found installed product - ssms
2/16/2016 9:02:47 AM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall(Boolean isRepairSupported)
at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using express edition( may be not ). As the error explains that the extension which you are trying to install is not supported to the VS edition you are using. There are restrictions on what you can install to each edition, Some extensions are available only for Community edition, enterprise. I guess you get the point. Paid edition supports more features and extensions than the free ones. But community edition must have it all but its not for enterprise use.

Comment: Is there a way to migrate from vs for web to vs community

Comment: I think you just have to install it separately, you can download from the Microsoft website itself.

Comment: You can still have your VS for web and community edition running together on your machine. Both will be separate software's

Comment: You mean i need to download vs community separately and i can run both on a single machine